# How to I get following menu structure with knp menu bundle?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.3, knpmenubundle, knpmenu

Im trying to get the following menu structure but I didn't find solution for it without a terrible hack in the core source of the knp menu bundle.

**My output is at the moment:**

```
<ul class="nav nav-list">
  <li class="open">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">
      Systembenutzer
    </a>
    <ul class="submenu" style="display: block;">...</ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

**And I wanna get this:**

```
<ul class="nav nav-list">
  <li class="open">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">
      <i class="icon-user"></i>
      <span class="menu-text">Systembenutzer
        <b class="arrow icon-angle-down pull-right"></b>
      </span>
    </a>
    <ul class="submenu" style="display: block;">...</ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

I'm not able to set for the label the following tags < i >, < span >, < b >.
Is there any solution to get that working?
Notice that the structure posted above is required because there is a dropdown menu implemented with javascript.

Comment: have a look at mopabootstrapbundle. It has methods for adding Icons and dropdowns to menus. (With Twitter Bootstrap, which I assume you are using)

Comment: Thx for the info. But doesn't exactly fix my issue at the moment. I've to check first if I can include the mopabootstrap bundle without geting in conflict with current installed. I use a customized bootstrap theme for my project...

Comment: Have you found a solution for your problem?

Comment: It's a bit tricky but I've found a option which allows you to output safe labels. So the html code get's rendered. But I'm not sure how I have solve this issue. I've to take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood well you need a new style for menu item. Why don't you define additional style as of

```
<style type="css/text">
   .nav-list ul li >a {
   font-style: italic;
   /* options from yours class="menu-text" style */
  }
   .nav-list ul li:after >a { 
  /* options from yours class="arrow icon-angle-down pull-right" style     */
  }
</style>
```

it fits well if you'll change all view of

. Also you could use

```
$menu->setChildrenAttribute('class', 'icon-user menu-text');
```

in your php menu definition

Comment: Hi thx for your response. That's correct and will be work but I've a special requirement. The requirement is exactly that structure I've post above. I also use the ->setChildrenAttribute to get the base attributes I need. But the issue is that the inner tags are required. So I need something like $menu->setHtmlLabel() instead of simple string name.